# not found assets laravel vite

Tags: php, laravel, vite

I install my Laravel 10.10 project on an AWS EC2 instance, then run `npm install` and everything is correct, then run `npm build` and everything worked.

The files were generated in:

- `/public/build/assets/app-6e0eadfb.js`
- `/public/build/assets/app-1766b808.css`

When I navigate to that path, it indicates that they do not exist.

##### `app.blade.php` code

```
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
```

Any recommendation?

Comment: It is a production environment

I made a file a.php with phpinfo() in /public/build/assets/ folder

When I enter the file from the browser it runs correctly

When I see the app-1766b808.css file from the browser it returns a 404 error although the file exists

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct the problem, the nginix server did not have CSS and JS reading enabled

use the configuration:

> ```
> location ~ \.css {
>      add_header Content-Type text/css;
> }
> location ~ \.js {
>      add_header Content-Type application/x-javascript;
> }
> ```